# code in addition overload having no effect

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

I'm working through an old book of C++ at the moment, and in it was developed a "rational numbers" class to introduce the idea of operator overloading, etc. Here's some example code from the book:

**interface**:

```
const Rational operator+(const Rational& Rhs) const;
```

**implementation:**

```
const Rational Rational::operator+(const Rational& Rhs) const
{
    Rational Answer(*this);
    Answer += Rhs;
    return Answer;
}
```

The copy constructor does what you think it would do, and the += operator is correctly overloaded.

I decided to practice a bit by implementing a string class, and so I took a similar approach. My `+=` overload works fine, but the `+` seems to have no effect ultimately.

**interface:**

```
const String operator+(const String&) const;
```

**implementation:**

```
const String String::operator+(const String& Rhs) const
{
    String Answer (*this);
    Answer += Rhs;
    return Answer;
}
```

where the copy constructor (which works) is defined as such:

```
String::String(const String& str)
{
    unsigned _strlen = str.len() + 1;
    content = new char[_strlen];
    std::memcpy(content, str.content, _strlen);
    length = _strlen - 1;
    content[length] = '\0';
}
```

and `+=` is overloaded by the following:

```
const String& String::operator+=(const String& Rhs)
{
    unsigned _Addl = Rhs.len();
    unsigned newLen = _Addl + length;  //length is member variable -- current length of content

    content = (char*) realloc( content, newLen+1 );

    std::memcpy(content+length, Rhs.content, _Addl);
    content[newLen] = '\0';

    return *this;
}
```

However -- while I can get proper output for `+=`, the `+` operator is failing to actually return a concatenated string. With debugging outputs inside of the function, `Answer` is holding the correct content, but it returns the original String instead of the concatenated one. I have a feeling this is something to do with `const`'s being everywhere, but I've tried without it as well to no good fortune.

Test Code:

(in main):

```
String s1 ("Hello");
String s2 (" World!");
String s3 = (s1+s2);       //prints "Hello" when s3 is output
cout << (s1+s2) << endl;   //prints "Hello"
```

String constructor for const char*

```
String::String(const char* str)
{
    unsigned _strlen = strlen(str) + 1;
    content = new char[_strlen];
    std::memcpy(content, str, _strlen);
    length = _strlen - 1;
    content[length] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Show your test code.

Comment: By the way, old books on C++ may not be a good investment of your time. They'll teach you outdated techniques.

Comment: `content = (char*)malloc(_strlen);`  Using `malloc` in a C++ program?  Why?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie bad style because I'm coming from C. shame on me, I guess

Comment: `unsigned newLen = _Addl + length;`  Where did `length` come from?  Is it a member variable?  If so, why isn't it updated?

Comment: sorry. length is a member variable containing the length of the string in `this`.

Comment: Returning const object inhibit move semantics. I recommend against it.

Comment: @jaska  You failed to update the `length` member variable.  And if `realloc` returns NULL, what are you going to do?  Your code will exhibit undefined behavior since it will just forge ahead and attempt to execute the rest of the function.  On the other hand, if you used `new [ ]`, an exception would be thrown on error, and none of that subsequent code would be executed (thus your object won't get corrupted).

Comment: The constructor is in the post, and len() just returns the member variable `length` which is an `unsigned`.

Comment: added, but it's basically the same as the original copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `String::operator+=()`, despite your claim it is properly implemented, is not properly implemented.

Firstly, `realloc()` returns `NULL` if it fails, and your code is not checking for that.

Second, and more critical, is that the `length` member is not being updated.  Since your code calls the `len()` member function to get the length of one string, and uses the `length` member to get the length of the other, all of your functions need to ensure those two methods are in sync (i.e. that they give consistent results for a given instance of `String`).   Since `length` is not being updated, your code does not ensure that.

There are probably better approaches than using C-style memory allocation as well, but (assuming this is a learning exercise) I'll leave that alone.

You've given no pertinent code for your `Rational` class but, if it is not working, your code presumably exhibits similar inconsistencies between what various constructors and member functions do.

Comment: actually, this seems to have fixed it. I also updated to use `new` instead of `malloc`, and I'm using a temporary `char*` to get rid of `realloc` usage.